# Local Push Notification with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement local push notification using DependencyService for Xamarin Forms.
Here the interface :

```
public interface INotification
    {
        void SetNotification(DateTime notificationDate, TimeSpan notificationTime);
    }
```

And here is andriod the implementation:

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(NotificationService))]
namespace TestMVVM.Droid
{
    public class NotificationService : INotification
    {
        public void SetNotification(DateTime notificationDate, TimeSpan notificationTime)
        {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle("Test Notification")
                .SetContentText("Notification from Xamarin Forms");
        }
    }
}
```

It is showing error on `Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)` as :

> Cannot Convert from 'TestMVVM.Droid.NotificationService' to
>   'Andriod.Content.Context'

I do understand the issue. `Context` allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc (refer : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Context/#Remarks). As it is an abstract class, I can not create object and pass it to constructor of `Builder`.
How can I pass context to the Builder Constructor?

Edit : Thanks for the help. It is working but notification is not showing only the sound is working. here the code:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context)
                .SetContentTitle("Test Notification")
                .SetContentText("Notification from Xamarin Forms")
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis());

            Notification notification = builder.Build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                        Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context`

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(NotificationService))]
namespace TestMVVM.Droid
{
    public class NotificationService : INotification
    {
        public void SetNotification(DateTime notificationDate, TimeSpan notificationTime)
        {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder (Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context)
                .SetContentTitle ("Test Notification")
                .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.AlertDarkFrame)
                .SetWhen (Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis ())
                .SetDefaults (NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                .SetContentText ("Notification from Xamarin Forms");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works. But I have run into another issue. The notification is not showing, only the sound is working. I have edited the question. Please look

Comment: Not good idea modify the original question, it was better you created a new thread, but we are already here. The notification is not showing because you didn't set an icon. Set anything so you can test it. Use `.SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.AlertDarkFrame)`